# Safe method for stopping an operation inside a dll

Tags: c++, c, gcc, dll

Suppose you have a DLL with a function `Foo` that has either a very large count, i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < 1,000,000,000; i++)` or a loop of the `while(something == true)` sort and you want to be able to interrupt this function from outside the DLL, what is the safest way to do this?

Many thank in advance

Comment: are you really using gcc to compile your code into a dll?

Comment: Yeah, I need the code to be cross platform so decided on MinGW GCC.

Comment: Make the loop test for a condition you can set from outside the DLL.

Comment: Won't this end in a race condition problem?

Comment: If this concurrently accessed variable wouldn't be protected: Yes

Comment: Would this then also require passing a mutex or something of the sort into the DLL in order to protect it?

Comment: I'd do this by running the loop on a thread and provide interruptible semantics. Then export that interrupt function.

Comment: Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a flag inside the DLL, which is tested by the long-runner.

Add a method to the DLL that sets this flag. Export this method.

Add appropriate protection to be used when accessing the flag.

---

**Update**

The protection mechanics need to be established when the flag is instantiated.

For a DLL global flag you would create a DLL global mutex during DLL initialisation.

The flag, along with the mutex protecting its access do not need to be accessable from the outside the DLL.

Comment: Just use std::atomic_bool instead?